# Javascript regex: get all numbers having between 2 and 6 digits but not 5

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a regex that check if the input string is a number between 2 and 6 digits but not 5. Obviously, I can do something like:

```
^[0-9]{2,4}$|^[0-9]{6}$
```

but I was hoping for more succinct notation.

This is JavaScript regex. Do you think there is a shorter answer?

Many thanks!

Comment: You mean that the string has a **length** of 2-6 but not 5, as that's what the regex is checking for, not the numbers themselves ?

Comment: I would personnally use something else than regexp. Like converting numbers to strings and test their length.

Comment: @adeneo he says "digits", so it's the length.

Comment: Then I'd do `!isNaN(parseFloat(numb)) && isFinite(numb) && numb.length >= 2 && numb.length <= 6 && numb.length != 5` it's a lot longer and not very pretty, but why use a regex when you don't have to.

Comment: @adeneo For the moment I only care about that, not the numbers themselves.

Comment: @adeneo for convenience I use the regex. I can use a predefined "RegexValidator" library that automatically outputs an error message in the UI. I could indeed check the same with some code, but then I would have to define my own validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.{5}$)\d{2,6}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/116

Comment: Yes, same question from me :-). Although it has an extra character compared to Paul Roub's answer, I "like" more the use of the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 3):

A more-succint version of the same logic:

```
^(\d{2,4}|\d{6})$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^(\d{2,3}|\d{4}(\d{2})?)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG8xI2/1)

Comment: This will match 5 digits - 3 in the first match, 2 in the second.

Comment: This is no longer shorter than the original.

Comment: Yes Paul's regex is even shorter